# Transforming EC public key X and Y-sign into X and Y

Tags: elliptic-curves

I'm using bouncycastle which uses X and Y coordinates for public keys.

An EC public key is more compactly represented by the X coordinate and the sign of the Y coordinate.

How do I use bouncycastle to transform X and Y into X and Y-sign, and vice versa. (The curve is secp256k1 if that makes any difference.)

Comment: Do you want to know how this is done mathematically ("point compression") or do you want to know how to do this with BouncyCastle?

Comment: I think the above should answer this. If the problem is how to do it using BC APIs, that's more of a programming question that should be asked somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it is a duplicate, I will delete this question.